# How to test ngrx/effects in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic3, ngrx

I'm trying to write some test for my ngrx effects in Ionic, but can't get it to work. There are several tutorials online, but they are either not applicable to my case or depcreated. The example in the [official ngrx migration guide](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) e.g. does not work anymore.

I want to test the case where a LoadAllAction is dispatched handled by the loadAllAction$ effect, and then finally a LoadAllCompleteAction is dispatched.

Here is my code. I renamed the classes and services to be more clear, so if there are spelling error please overlook it. The imports are all correct in the real code as well.

**myEffects.effects.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Actions, Effect} from "@ngrx/effects";
import {catchError, concat, map, switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {IMyObject} from "../models/myObject.model";
import {MyObjectService} from "../../services/myObject.service";
import {
  InitMyObjectsCompleteAction,
  LOAD_ALL,
  LOAD_ALL_COMPLETE,
  LoadAllAction,
  LoadAllCompleteAction,
  SaveMyObjectsCompleteAction, MyObjectsErrorAction
} from "../actions/object.actions";
import {defer} from "rxjs/observable/defer";
import {LogService} from "../../services/log/log.service";
import {ToastService} from "../../services/toast.service";

@Injectable()
export class MyEffects {

  constructor(private action$: Actions,
              private myObjectService: MyObjectService,
              private logService: LogService,
              private toastService: ToastService) {
  }

  @Effect() init$ = defer(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.myObjectService.getSavedMyObjects())
    .pipe(
      map((favoredObjects: IMyObject[]) => new InitMyObjectsCompleteAction(favoredObjects)),
      catchError((error) => this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error)),
      concat(Observable.of(new LoadAllAction()))
    ));

  @Effect() loadAllAction$ = this.action$.ofType(LOAD_ALL).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.myObjectService.loadObjects().pipe(
      map((favoredObjects: IMyObject[]) => new LoadAllCompleteAction(favoredObjects)),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.toastService.couldNotUpdateObject();
        return this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error)
      })
    ))
  );

  @Effect() loadAllCompleteAction$ = this.action$.ofType(LOAD_ALL_COMPLETE).pipe(
    switchMap((action: LoadAllCompleteAction) => Observable.fromPromise(this.myObjectService.saveObjects(action.favoredObjects))
      .pipe(
        map(() => new SaveMyObjectsCompleteAction()),
        catchError((error) => this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error))
      )
    )
  );

  private createErrorObservableAndLog(error){
    this.logService.error(error);
    return Observable.of(new MyObjectsErrorAction(error))
  }
}
```

**mocks.ts**

```
export class MyObjectsServiceMock {

  loadMyObjects(): Observable<MyObjects[]> {
    return createDummyMyObjectsListObservable();
  }
}

export class StorageMock {
  get() {
    return [];
  }

  set() {

  }
}
export class StoreMock {

  private returnMyObjects: boolean = false;

  public dispatch() {
    return Observable.empty();
  }

  public select() {
    if (this.returnMyObjects)
      return createDummyMyObjectsListObservable();
    return Observable.empty();
  }

  public setReturnObjects(wantMyObjects: boolean) {
    this.returnMyObjects = wantMyObjects;
  }
}
```

Here is the test as it is so far. No matter what tutorial I try by itself, combined with others - it's not working, at all, and I have a really hard time figuring out where to even start. In this following example actions doesn't have the property 'next' since it's an observable, even though I copied it pretty much straight from the migration guide. The expect().toBe() in the 'Should also work' - Test is not correct either - but I can't find the documentation of the correct syntax.

**myEffects.effects.spec.ts**

```
import {TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {MyObjectServiceMock, StorageMock, StoreMock} from "../../../test-config/mocks-ionic";
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {LogService} from "../../services/log/log.service";
import {MyEffects} from "./myEffects.effects";
import {MyObjectService} from "../../services/myObject.service";
import {provideMockActions} from "@ngrx/effects/testing";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {cold, hot} from 'jasmine-marbles';
import {InitMyObjectsCompleteAction, LoadAllAction, LoadAllCompleteAction} from "../actions/myObject.actions";
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";
import {ToastService} from "../../services/toast.service";
import {ToastController} from "ionic-angular";
import {ReplaySubject} from "rxjs/ReplaySubject";

describe('MyObject Effects', () => {
  let myObject: MyObjectEffects;
  let actions: Observable<any>;


  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyObjectEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
        ToastService,
        ToastController,
        LogService,
        {provide: Store, useClass: StoreMock},
        {provide: MyObjectService, useClass: MyObjectServiceMock},
        {provide: Storage, useClass: StorageMock}
      ]
    })
    myObjectEffects = TestBed.get(MyObjectEffects);
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    actions = hot('--a-', {a: InitMyObjectsCompleteAction});
    const expected = cold('--b', {b: LoadAllCompleteAction});

    expect(myObjectEffects.loadAllCompleteAction$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });

 it('should work also', () => {
    actions = new ReplaySubject(1);

    actions.next(new LoadAllAction());

    myObjectEffects.loadAllCompleteAction$.subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toBe(new LoadAllCompleteAction());
    });
  });

});
```

Basically it boils down to 2 issues:

**1. How do I configure the TestBed the right way and do I even have to
    mock everything?**

**2. How would I correctly test the correct course of
    dispatched actions as described above and in the code?**

I'm obviously not asking for you to write the tests for me - but maybe you have an idea where I can get started or point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, maybe the solution it will help someone in the future.

1. Inject the effects and mocked services from the TestBed in beforeEach()

   `service = TestBed.get(MyObjectService);
   myObjecEffects = TestBed.get(MyObjectEffects);`
2. Mock the actions as a ReplaySubject of Type Action:

   `provideMockActions(() => actions)`
3. Subscribe to each effect that I want to test in the process:

   `myObjectEffects.loadAllAction$.subscribe((result) => {})`
4. In each subscription test for any calls or other things you want to test and feed a new value to the actions-subject:

   `myObjectEffects.loadAllAction$.subscribe((result) => actions.next(result))`.
5. Repeat for each effect you want to test.

Since this might not make it very clear, here is the whole test:

```
describe('MyObject Effects', () => {
  let myObjectEffects: MyObjectEffects;
  let actions: ReplaySubject<Action>;
  let service: MyObjectService;


  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyObjectsApp],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyObjectsApp)
      ],
      providers: [
        MyObjectEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
        ToastService,
        ToastController,
        LogService,
        {provide: MyObjectService, useClass: MyObjectServiceMock},
        {provide: Store, useClass: StoreMock}
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MyObjectService);
    myObjectEffects = TestBed.get(MyObjectEffects);
  });

  it('loadAll action should eventually save objects', () => {
    actions.next(new LoadAllAction());
    spyOn(service, 'loadObjects').and.returnValue(Observable.of([new Object({id: 20})]));
    myObjectEffects.loadAllAction$.subscribe((result) => {
      expect(service.loadObjects).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(result).toEqual(new LoadAllCompleteAction([new Object({id: 20})]));
      actions.next(result);
    });
    objectEffects.loadAllCompleteAction$.subscribe((result) => {
      expect(result).toEqual(new SaveObjectsCompleteAction());
    });
  })
});
```